# Наложение картинки на слайдер

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

У меня есть картинка и слайдер, они одинаковых размеров и мне нужно наложить их на друг друга, но почему то даже не могу поставить эту картинку по середине через margin: 0 auto;, при этом я не хочу делать отступ в пикслеях, так как придется морочится с  медиа запросами
Так как это реализовать? Или хотяб пофиксить margin 0 auto

```
    <div class="txttop">Эксклюзивный Рандом!</div>
<br>
<div class="slbg"><img src="img/slbg.png"></div>
<div class="sl">
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/1.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/2.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/3.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/4.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/5.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/6.png"></div>
    <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/7.png"></div>
</div>
<div class="button"><a href="#">Испытать удачу за 49 рублей</a></div>

.sl {
width: 750px;
margin: 0 auto;
border: 3px solid #fff;
background-color: #fff;
padding: 17px 0px;
}
.slide img {
margin: 0 auto;
z-index: 1;
}
.slbg {
position: absolute;
z-index: 2;
}
.slbg img {

}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: position:absolute

Comment: Все равно не хочет вставать по середине.

Comment: Расшифруйте рисунок - кто есть картинка, кто слайдер и где середина

Comment: А где код?.....

Comment: Шипи с двух сторон + оранжевая линия = png картинка, Там где игры - слайдер

Comment: Добавил код, пришлось убрать скрин из-за ограничение по баллам (подкиньте баллов ;) )

Comment: @BreeL никто не кинет баллов. Люди будут помогать только если ваш код можно редактировать. Добавьте код текстом.

Comment: Какое-то безумие .... Ну ладно хоть не на фотоаппарат сфоткал ... При создании сообщения есть вставка "фрагемент кода ..." используй с умом иначе действительно какое-то издевательство.

Comment: Да и вообще, если это slBG, то зачем использовать наложение, когда можно использовать background?

Comment: Извиняюсь, первый раз на stackoverflow, вставил код

Comment: @MedvedevDev надо чтоб картинка была поверх сладера

Answer (score -1, accepted):

добавь картинке **display: block;** и будет **margin: 0 auto;** работать

```
<div class="sl">
  <div class="slbg"><img src="img/slbg.png"></div>

  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/1.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/2.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/3.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/4.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/5.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/6.png"></div>
  <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/7.png"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sl{
  position: relative;
}
.slbg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slide{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Краткость сестра таланта, но немного  больше информациии было бы не лишне.

Comment: заставили дополнить

Answer (score 0):

Конечно структура очень странная, но тем не менее кажется я понял что к чему. Как минимум нужно добавить общий контейнер. К тому же тут увидел br после div он не нужен, так как див и так блочный элемент, нужен отступ после дива - делай margin, а так ...

**CSS**

```
.sl {
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 17px 0px;
}
.slide img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
.slbg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.slbg img {

}

// needly styles

.sl-container { position: relative; }

.sl {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slbg {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="sl-container">
  <div class="slbg">
    <img src="img/slbg.png">
  </div>
  <div class="sl">
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/1.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/2.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/3.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/4.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/5.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/6.png"></div>
      <div class="slide"><img src="img/games/7.png"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="button"><a href="#">Испытать удачу за 49 рублей</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Сделал как ты написал, ничего не изменилось.